# Как реализовать много разных webbrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser

может кто подскажет как логичнее реализовать мою задачу)
В общем есть сайт на который я захожу с помощью webbrowser и там я делаю свои действия
но у меня есть на нем 10 аккаунтов, и я хотел бы сделать прогу многопоточной чтобы она одновременно делала 10 веббраузеров не зависящих друг от друга и не хранящие куки друг друга, и чтобы они делали тоже самое что и основной только по своим требованиям
через httpwebrequest этого не сделать никак(

Comment: [Parallel Testing With Selenium Webdriver – Automation on Steroids](https://simpleprogrammer.com/parallel-testing-selenium-webdriver-automation-steroids/)?

Comment: интересный вариант, но может кто то что то ещё подскажет

Comment: `httpwebrequest этого не сделать никак` - почему? В 90% случаев, отправка простого запроса на определенный адрес решает все поставленные задачи.

Comment: к сожалению все на websocketАХ, поэтому реквестом вроде как не получается, или я туплю очень